# Configuring a get.tech domain on AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-cloudfront

I have spent hours trying to configure a domain I bought from get.tech on AWS Route 53. What records do I need to include on route53 and what records do I include on my get.tech control panel?

I have tried manually adding NS (nameserver) records but am still unable to configure it properly; I have a Terraform config I have used to setup ACM, CloudFront, S3 etc. using a separate domain which I bought from AWS but I am having issues with this external domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a hostzone with your domain in Route53
- Copy the nameservers under the `NS` type in the newly created route53 record, and add them to your domain provider name servers list.
- After a certain period (typically 1 hr to 24 hrs), you can add records from the route53 and control your domain.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am currently waiting a few hours to see if changes to the route53 records will reflect

Comment: Worked perfectly! Appreciate the guidance